# What R package or code can be used to build custom-made GUIs?

Tags: r, user-interface

I am looking to create GUI that takes in a few inputs from the user (for example gender, age, and race as clickable categories), then assigns a user ID to each input (which would be displayed as the output in the GUI).  Under the hood would be a dataset that the GUI is creating with this user input (In this example, it would be 4 variables: user ID, gender, age, and race).

Has anyone created a GUI like this before?  Any R package or code recommendations?

Thanks!

Comment: This question is likely to get good, full answers on SO.

Comment: What about web-based GUIs, e.g. there exist Apache modules - or are you interested in a GUI very tied to R?

Comment: For that matter, if you are amenable to web-based surveys, there are some good systems out there, and some good R software to analyze the output of such standard survey systems.  Up to you, I'm only asking to get clarification of your needs.

Comment: @Iterator: exactly. R as a survey (conduction) tool? Or is it rather, some interactive analysis for people who don't like the console?
Captain Murphy: UCLA? Can't you just ask Jeroen? Don't think there a lot of people better than him when it comes to web based R GUIs.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this. Here is one using the add-on package gWidgets. Should work with either RGtk2 or tcltk backends.

```
library(gWidgets)
items <- data.frame(id=numeric(0), gender=character(0), age=numeric(0), race=character(0), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
genders <- c("Male", "Female")
race <- c("Black", "Hispanic", "Other")

w <- gwindow("Capn's GUI", visible=FALSE)
g <- ggroup(cont=w, horizontal=FALSE)
lyt <- glayout(cont=g)
lyt[1,1] <- "Gender:"
lyt[1,2] <- gradio(genders, cont=lyt)

lyt[2,1] <- "Age:"
lyt[2,2] <- gedit("40", coerce.with=as.numeric, cont=lyt)

lyt[3,1] <- "Race:"
lyt[3,2] <- gcombobox(race, selected=0L, cont=lyt)

lyt[4,2] <- gbutton("Add", cont=lyt, handler=function(h,...) {
  vals <- lapply(lyt[1:3, 2], svalue)
  id <- nrow(items) + 1                 # or roll your own
  items[id, ] <<- c(id, vals)
  tbl[] <- items
})
gseparator(cont=g)
tbl <- gtable(items, cont=g)


visible(w) <- TRUE
```

Answer (score 7):

There is a new solution build on top of RStudio.  It was presented in useR2011, here is a link to the poster:

http://www.calvin.edu/~rpruim/talks/MosaicLightning/images/mosaicManipulate-poster.pdf

Comment: For non-rstudio users, you can use gWidgetsManipulate the exact same way as Tal points to. This package is not on cran, but r-forge, at the moment: https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=761

Comment: @jverzani What is the fate of `gWidgetsManipulate`? Was it ported to `gWidgets2`? I think it would be nice to have a non-RStudio manipulate-like package on CRAN..

Comment: There is an example here: https://github.com/jverzani/gWidgets2/blob/master/inst/examples/manipulate.R

Answer (score 1):

Another nice option i tried is to build a GUI using JavaFx , http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/overview/jfxpub-overview.htm, and in the JavaFx GUI , just use JRI, http://rforge.net/JRI/, which will enable you to use R within Java.